# Commit a renamed and edited file in git, reliably, in a single commit?

Tags: git, github

I have both renamed and moved a file in git. I took the `bar.js` file, edited the contents extensively, and moved it across directories.

This is what `git status` is showing me:

```
$ git status

On branch feature/bar-chart
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

deleted:    js/journey-graph/bar.js

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

js/bar-chart/bar.js
```

I'd like to make a *single commit* that encompasses both the rename and the editing, and preserves the history attached to the file.

Is this possible with git?

Please note: I don't want to rely on git spotting automatically that the files are similar, and guessing that they have been renamed rather than manually added and deleted. I want to tell git exactly what has happened. (This is because I actually have quite a few edited files, and I'm nervous about git getting them confused.)

Answer (score 1):

Git commit does not care about renames.

Commit simply writes a commit that records the complete state of a work-tree (plus the usual other commit data).  "The state of a work tree" never has any renaming in it.  It just has files.  File `a.js` exists, or does not.  File `b.js` exists, or does not.

Renaming comes in when (and *only* when) you ask git to *compare* two trees.  You can, for instance, ask git to compare "tree in latest commit" with "tree in working directory".  That's what `git status` does.

You can also ask git to compare the trees of two different commits:

```
git diff HEAD~7 HEAD~2  # what changed between "7 commits ago" and "2 ago"
```

and `git diff` takes options—`-M`, `-C`, and so on—that let you control how aggressive git gets in terms of rename and copy detection.  The `git status` command has no options for this; its rename-detector is permanently set to a moderate level.

The key point, though, is all this happens *when you run the **other** commands:* `git commit` simply records a tree, and it's later (and earlier!), with *other* git commands, that git attempts to figure out whether things were renamed and/or copied.

Answer (score 1):

You can go

```
git mv file newname    # Rename
edit, edit, edit, ...  # Mangle
git add newname        # Make *sure* the last version gets saved
git commit             # Away we go
```

No changes are really recorded until the commit. And `git mv` does exactky the same as deleting the old file and creating a new one with the same contents, as far as git cares. *How* the contents moved from one place to the other is none of git's concern.

Comment: But what should I do given that I have *already* edited the file, without running `git mv` first?

Comment: @Richard, you can `git mv` afterwards too.